# Swift equivalent to `initWithContentsOfFile:`?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the Swift equivalent of `initWithContentsOfFile:` on an `Array`.  The documentation states that the equivalent is `convenience init(contentsOfFile aPath: String!)`

I have tried to call this with the following code:

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Standards", ofType: "plist")
var rawStandards = Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>>(contentsOfFile: path)
```

The compiler is telling me, however, that it couldn't find an overload that accepts the supplied arguments.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

@Leo Natan was really close,  but the way that worked for me was:

```
var rawStandards = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
```

I was then able to access the elements:

```
for obj: AnyObject in rawStandards {
    if var rawStandard = obj as? NSDictionary {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are initializing a Swift array, not an `NSArray`, which has the `initWithContentsOfFile:` initializer method.

Try:

```
var rawStandards = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>[]
```

Comment: I'll test in a few minutes. There is no reason why it shouldn't. Try using `path as NSString` instead.

Comment: Why are you casting to a `Dictionary` instead of an `Array`?

Comment: @Bill Notice the "[]" at the end? That's the syntax for array.

Comment: I had to use var `rawStandards = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject?>]`

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Standards", ofType: "plist")
    var menuItemArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as NSArray!
```

this is what i'm using myself. in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. I've verified it in the beta build of Xcode. Unlike the other answers, I wanted a native typed Swift array with the results, so I took a few extra steps. (@wayne-hartman's answer may be more intuitive if you don't know what you have in your plist or don't want a typed Array.) It did require forcing types in a way I didn't expect.

My plist has dictionaries at the first level and strings at the second level, the code should be easy to adjust for other types.

```
    let plistNSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myplist", ofType: "plist")
    let untypedArray: AnyObject[] = plistNSArray
    let typedArray = untypedArray as Dictionary<String,String>[] //Obviously you could do this conditionally for better error handling
    for plistDictItem in typedArray {
        for (dictKey,dictValue) in plistDictItem {
            println("key \(dictKey) has value \(dictValue)")
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work (or at least I couldn't make it work) without the intermediate step of `untypedArray`.

@leo-natan's doesn't compile for me, even though it looks like it should to me. I believe that the compiler just can't automatically convert the NSArray into a typed Swift array directly without the intermediate step I added. It wouldn't surprise me if his code works in a future release.